# Refer a global variable that has same name as the local variable in Python

Tags: python

I am new to python, how can we refer a global variable that has the same name as local one.

```
spam = 'global spam'
def scope_test():
    spam = 'local spam'
    print(spam)
    # access global spam and print or assign to the local spam
    # print(global.spam)
    # local.spam = global.spam (something like this)

scope_test()
```

Comment: You can't, nor does it make sense to. You should avoid both global state and name shadowing.

Comment: You could   `print(globals()["spam"])` but don't.

Comment: Or `import sys; print(sys.modules[__name__].spam)`, but it's still not a good idea

Comment: can't you define `def scope_test(spam): ... return spam` and run `spam = scope_test(spam)`

Comment: @furas: The OP doesn't want the function to modify the global `spam`.

Comment: @PM2Ring I add `spam = ` (and `return spam`) automatically.

Comment: Thanks all for sharing the insights, i understand it would create more confusion if we use same name in global and local scope. Since i have done some programming in Java and JavaScript, i am used to interpolate the concepts that i am learning in python with them. Not that i have done such thing in Java or JavaScript but just that it is possible there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's something not recommended, I am answering it for the sake if you're curious to ask/do it:

```
Python 3.5.2 
>>> spam = 'global spam'
>>> def scope_test(): 
..     spam = 'local spam' 
..     print(spam) 
..     # access global spam and print or assign to the local spam 
..     print(globals()['spam']) 
..     spam = globals()['spam'] 
..     print(spam) 
..     
>>> scope_test()
```

The output:

```
local spam
global spam
global spam
```