# python nested function variable scope

Tags: python, nested-function

I know about nonlocal keyword and how to fix this error but I am getting a behaviour that I am not understanding in the code below. If you run this, there is no problem

```
def test( root):
        x=2
        def f2(r):
            print("***")
            x=r #Adding this line is ok
            print("----",x)
        f2(root)
        return x
test(4)
```

Now try changing x=r  to be be the last line in f2 does not work as below

```
def test( root):
        x=2
        def f2(r):
            print("***")
            print("----",x)
            x=r #Gives an error "local variable 'x' referenced before assignment"
        f2(root)
        return x
test(4)
```

Thanks

Comment: The `x`'s are different in the two assigns. When you do `x=r` its a different variable. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39805893/refer-a-global-variable-that-has-same-name-as-the-local-variable-in-python). Also check example 6 [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/global-local-nonlocal-variables).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two variables named 'x', in two different scopes.  I would not recommend doing this; it can lead to a lot of confusion, leading to bugs in the program.

I would not suggest fixing this with keywords.  Rename one of the variables.  If you do, the error becomes clear.

```
def test( root):
        x_test=2
        def f2(r):
            print("***")
            print("----",x_f2)
            x_f2=r 
        f2(root)
        return x_test
test(4)
```

Clearly, x_f2 is being referenced before assignment.  When you write the code like this, the error is clear.

This is *exactly*  what your code is doing; it is just not clear because you have two variables with the same name, in different scopes.

The 'x' inside f2 is a local variable in the function, and you can not use it before assigning it.  The fact that in the outer scope there is a different variable named 'x' which has been assigned, does not change that.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in line 5 where you printed `x` in `print("----",x)`, 
it doesnt know the `x` in f2 function so you cant print it

if you want to use that `x=2` in `f2()` you should pass it to it , or using the global key or ...

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, you're assigning a new local variable `x` that is independent of the `x` in the outer scope.  Since you assign this value before you use it, that's fine.  The `x` that you assign `4` to is the one that's local to `f2`, which is why when you return `x` from `test` it's the original `2` value.

In the second example, you do the same thing of assigning a new local variable `x` (which causes the outer scope's `x` to be shadowed, same as before), but this time you reference it before you actually do the assignment.  That's what generates the error.

If you didn't assign `x` at all, then it wouldn't be shadowed and you would be able to `print` its value from the outer scope (meaning you'd see its value as 2, not 4):

```
>>> def test( root):
...         x=2
...         def f2(r):
...             print("***")
...             print("----",x)
...         f2(root)
...         return x
...
>>> test(4)
***
---- 2
2
```